# How does one expand an open Excel workspace to use 100% of the available window when maximized?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm not familiar with the terms exactly so if I need to be corrected please update my post.

The picture should exemplify what I'm trying to achieve.  The colored areas are not naturally colored so ignore the colors if trying to find them on another instance of Excel 2010.
[image]

Comment: It appears that under normal conditions the worksheet would have its own window resize and close buttons.  In this particular case it appears that I don't have a normal condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top-right corner of the workspace should be a set of window buttons. Click the middle one, also known as "maximize":

[image: sample image illustrating where to click]

Comment: Or you can double-click on the titlebar.

Comment: Unfortunately that set of window resize and close options are not available with that worksheet.  Double clicking also has shown to fail with this problematic workbook.

Comment: Credit deserved where credit is due.  The underlying problem with my workbook was caused by modifying and saving the file with LibreOffice then later re-open with Microsoft Excel.  Many undesirable things happened, but this one puzzles me since it should be the application providing those key window features and not the workbook.  Good thing this file is backed up with versioning in mind!